# Android - Make default tabs but without any content

Tags: android, view, tabs

So I want to have tabs with default style but I want to handle content by myself. 
If I try to create them only with:

`TabSpec tabT = mainTabHost.newTabSpec("tabT").setIndicator("T");
tabHost.add(tabT);`

I get error that content is not specified.

Then I tried to add tabs with tabwidget directly but I don't know how to get default style of tabs.

Any advice?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try `TabContentFactory` with an empty View:

```
tabSpec.setContent(new EmptyTabFactory());
```

the factory class:

```
private class EmptyTabFactory implements TabContentFactory {

    @Override
    public View createTabContent(String tag) {
        return new View(mContext);
    }

}
```

Comment: @Eugene a refference to some [Context](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html). You get it from the activity you are creating the tabs in.

Answer (score -1):

To set content you should use the method [setContent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TabHost.TabSpec.html#setContent%28int%29):

```
TabSpec tabT = mainTabHost.newTabSpec("tabT").setIndicator("T").setContent(viewId);
```

Take a look [here](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-tabwidget.html) for getting an example.

Comment: I know, but as it says in title I DO NOT want any content. Only tab indicator.

Comment: You have to set some content. If you dont want any - set empty view.